# JQuery width() does not return correct value

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div that has not a preset width in `css`, I'm trying to center in on screen with `JQuery`, it works in **Chrome**, **Firefox** and **IE8+**, but does not work in **IE7**. Why?

**css:**

```
.productBoxWrapper{
    height:210px;
    clear:both;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('#mydiv').css("position", "absolute");
this.css("left", ($(window).width() - $("#mydiv").width()) / 2 + "px");
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/tygcz/3/

Comment: IE7 is old, don't support it.

Comment: Do you have an containing divs with padding/margin? you may need to use [.outerWidth()](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/) instead to take account of padding and borders.

Comment: Agree with @s.lenders. Welcome to 2013. :-/

Comment: do you really need to support IE7? This is just one of hundred of problems and wasted time you will have when supporting IE7.

Comment: I hate the IE9- but the boss asked me!

Comment: Google dropped support for IE7 last year so when developing a new website don't bother making it work. IE7 is old, it updates automaticly to 8 on all windows. less then 2% of the users still use IE7. Not interesting to waste alot of time on

Comment: What version of jQuery do you have?

Comment: @AllanKimmerJensen 1.9

Comment: @s.lenders as someone who works for a company who's clients are based in the health industry, this isn't possible. They are the 2%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to center it like this:

Css:

```
#myDiv{
     position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;
}
```

Script:

```
$('#myDiv').css('marginLeft', - ( parseInt( $('#myDiv').width() ) / 2) + 'px' );
$('#myDiv').css('marginTop', - ( parseInt( $('#myDiv').height() ) / 2) + 'px' );
```

I'm not sure weather parseInt is really needed.